# How to insert Folium map with Markers in Dash layout?

Tags: python, iframe, maps, plotly-dash, folium

I have a map created using Folium saved as an HTML file. It contains a few markers.
Now I would like to insert this map as an IFrame element in my Plotly-Dash layout. I managed to do that using:

```
app.layout = html.Div(children=[
        html.Iframe(id='map', srcDoc=open('index.html', 'r').read())
], style={'padding': 10, 'flex': 1})
```

but the markers don't appear when embedded in the Dash layout. Why are they not appearing in  Dash?

Comment: Are you bound to use Folium? Or are solutions using other frameworks relevant?

Comment: No, I'm not bound to Folium. The thing is that it produced the exact map with markers I wanted, but the markers disappear when I embed that file into Dash. I'm not sure if it is Dash or Folium issue. Do you recommend using some other tool?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative to Folium is `dash-leaflet`. While both components are leaflet-based, `dash-leaflet` provides tighter integration with Dash. Here is a small example with a few markers,

```
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_leaflet as dl
from dash import Dash

# A few cities in Denmark.
cities = [dict(title="Aalborg", position=[57.0268172, 9.837735]),
          dict(title="Aarhus", position=[56.1780842, 10.1119354]),
          dict(title="Copenhagen", position=[55.6712474, 12.5237848])]
# Create example app.
app = Dash()
app.layout = html.Div([
    dl.Map(children=[dl.TileLayer()] + [dl.Marker(**city) for city in cities],
           style={'width': '100%', 'height': '50vh', 'margin': "auto", "display": "block"}, id="map"),
])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server()
```

You can see a lot more examples in [the documentation](http://dash-leaflet.herokuapp.com/).

Comment: dead link, http://dash-leaflet.herokuapp.com/  --> "there's nothing here yet" ?