# use Folium map in plotly subplots to create dashboard

Tags: python, plotly, geopandas, subplot, folium

I have a plan area that covers several buildings. I want to map the plan and the building in a subplot using `gdf.explore()` method that creates a folium map object, and then use plotly to map a graph of building years histogram. Then put these two plots side by side.

I could not find a way to add folium map object in plotly subplots.

Here is what I need in code:

```
m = gdf.explore()
p = px.histogram()


# CODE THAT PUTS m AND p IN ONE GRAPH!
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to insert Folium map with Markers in Dash layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69664270/how-to-insert-folium-map-with-markers-in-dash-layout)

Comment: Folium and plotly are based on two different JavaScript backends. You can put them next to each other with html (e.g. iframes for example) or switch to a single dashboard system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- your question does not contain sample geometry or dataframe.  Have synthesized some
- as per comments **plotly** and **folium** are very different libraries with no integration
- clearly with **HTML** you can integrate using **IFrame**. Have taken approach of using *data URI* to encode **plotly** and **folium** components into a single **HTML** document

```
import shapely.geometry
import numpy as np
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
from IPython.display import IFrame
from datauri import DataURI
from pathlib import Path

# create a folium map
m = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    geometry=[
        shapely.geometry.MultiPoint(
            np.random.uniform(b, b + 1, size=(5, 2))
        ).convex_hull
        for b in range(4)
    ],
    data={"building": [f"building {b}" for b in range(4)]},
).explore(column="building")

# create a histogram
fig = px.histogram(
    pd.DataFrame(
        np.random.randint(1980, 2022, size=(100, 4)),
        columns=[f"b {b}" for b in range(4)],
    )
    .stack()
    .reset_index()
    .rename(columns={0: "year", "level_1": "b"}),
    x="year",
    color="b",
).update_layout(margin={"l": 0, "r": 0, "t": 0, "b": 0})

html = f"""<html>
<body>
    <div style="display:inline-block;width:1200">
        <iframe src='{DataURI.make("text/html", charset="us-ascii", base64=True, data=m._parent.render())}' 
            width="49%", align="left"></iframe>
        <iframe src='{DataURI.make("text/html", charset="us-ascii", base64=True, data=fig.to_html(include_plotlyjs="cdn"))}'
            width="49%", align="right"></iframe>
    </div>
</body>
</html>"""

# as a HTML file
with open(Path.cwd().joinpath("sample.html"), "w") as f:
    f.write(html)

# as jupyter output
IFrame(
    DataURI.make("text/html", charset="utf-8", base64=True, data=html),
    height=900,
    width=1200,
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! 
I wanted to provide sample but I thought that with geometries it will make question unreadable.